# Tunneling through proxy & SSH server

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling, socks5-proxy

A SOCKS5 proxy is between my source and target servers. The source server can be accessed only from my local server.

I tried connecting through proxy option and SSH tunneling option in Winscp but the problem is as below:

The SOCKS5 proxy is used only for my source server(tunneled one) instead, I would like to use it for my target server. Please let me know how I can achieve this.

Flow:
Local system -> Source server -> SOCKS5 proxy -> Target server

Comment: Can you connect with `ssh` or `sftp` from the source server command-line to the target server?

Comment: No, there is a firewall in between and only the socks5 proxy can connect to target server

Comment: We know. But if you want to connect local > source > proxy > target, then you first need to be able to connect source > proxy > target. Or I do not understand your question.

Comment: Ok. Yes. The connections works. I have tested using the curl command.

curl --socks5 proxyhost:1080 sftp://targethost:22 -user user_name: --key /home/wmadmin/.ssh/private_key

Answer (score 0):

So you are connecting *local* > *source* > *proxy* > *target*.

First test a connection from *source* via *proxy* to the *target* using OpenSSH `ssh` command.

This should help you:
[How can I use SSH with a SOCKS 5 proxy?](https://superuser.com/q/454210/213663)

The command will be like (untested):

```
ssh -o ProxyCommand='/usr/bin/nc -X 5 -x proxyhost:1080 %h %p' user@host
```

The connection has to work without any intervention (so it would typically need to authenticate using an unencrypted private key).

---

Once you have that working, you can go to WinSCP (running on *local*) and configure it as if you were connecting to *source*. But additionally, on [Environment > SFTP page](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_login_sftp) on [Advanced site settings dialog](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_login_advanced), specify the *"SFTP server"* using the `ssh` command you have just made working on *source*. Just add [`-s sftp` switch](https://man.openbsd.org/sftp#s):

```
ssh -o ProxyCommand='/usr/bin/nc -X 5 -x proxyhost:1080 %h %p' -s sftp user@host
```

Comment: I have tried this command before. But nc is not installed and I'm not the administrator to install nc. I think there no way for me to connect through ssh to target :(

Comment: Did you try simple `nc` (without a path)? Maybe it's installed to a different folder. `nc` is pretty much a standard tool.

Comment: You can also implement `nc` equivalent using any scripting language that you have on the *source*, like Perl, PHP or Python. This looks like it might do what you need: https://github.com/dzonerzy/Pync/blob/master/nc.py (not tested). - I would not be surprised, if it was possible to use `curl` as `nc` replacement either.

Comment: Yes I tried nc and it says "-ksh: nc: not found [No such file or directory]". I can connect using curl but it does not offer same functionality as ssh. I will try if I can find something from script nc.py. Thanks for it.